# How to place subquery in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have a main SQL query which returns stock quantity in dates between and I also need to return the stock as on date along with between dates result.

Main query:

```
SELECT 
    TT.TranRId, MAX(TT.TInQty) AS InQty, MAX(TT.TOutQty) AS OutQty
FROM
    TReg TR, TTrans TT
WHERE 
    TR.TRegId = TT.TrRegId
    AND TT.Stid = 2
    AND TR.TransDate BETWEEN '2018-08-25' AND '2018-08-28'
GROUP BY 
    TT.TranRId 
ORDER BY 
    TT.TranRId
```

Sub query:

```
(SELECT TT.TransRId, (SUM(TT.TInQty) - SUM(TT.TOutQty)) 
FROM TTrans TT, TReg TR
WHERE TR.TransDate <= '2018-08-24' 
  AND TR.TRegId = TT.TrRegId
  AND TT.Stid = 2 GROUP BY TT.TranRId) --AS Stock
```

Please help where I should include my sub query in my main query

To get output as follows:

```
TransRId    Stock   InQty   OutQty
----------------------------------
41          700     1       1000
42          800     5       500
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In addition to accurate suggest above it would be helpful if we had more details to work with to help find you an answer. Here is a great place to start.http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Running total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I am following your question 100%, if you are just looking to join it as a sub query the below logic should work.

```
SELECT TT.TranRId
    ,MAX(TT.TInQty) AS InQty
    ,MAX(TT.TOutQty) AS OutQty
    ,Stock.[Sum]
FROM TReg TR
LEFT JOIN TTrans TT
    ON TR.TRegId = TT.TrRegId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TT.TransRId
        ,(SUM(TT.TInQty) - SUM(TT.TOutQty)) as Sum
    FROM TTrans TT
    LEFT JOIN TReg TR
        ON TR.TRegId = TT.TrRegId
    WHERE TR.TransDate <= '2018-08-24'
        AND TT.Stid = 2
    GROUP BY TT.TranRId
    ) AS Stock
    ON Stock.TranRId = TT.TranRId
WHERE TT.Stid = 2
    AND TR.TransDate BETWEEN '2018-08-25' AND '2018-08-28'
GROUP BY TT.TranRId
ORDER BY TT.TranRId
```

edit:
I noticed tt.TranRId and tt.Tran***s***RId  if this is not a typo it would need to be corrected, if not my answer will not work for you.

If you need specific dates, including the date in the join logic along with the ID would give you the appropriate result...without knowing your data set I am not sure if the TranRId is unique...sorry about that!

Comment: @Rennick Thanks for your suggestion its help me a lot and sorry for delay reply